# Getting values from FormPanel in ExtReact 6.6.0

Tags: javascript, extjs, extreact

How should I be getting values from a FormPanel using ext-react 6.6.0?

According to the [API documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extreact/6.6.0/modern/Ext.form.Panel.html) I should be using `getValues` function, that works in 6.5.1 but I get error `_this.form.getValues is not a function` in 6.6.0

**Code**

Works in 6.5.1: https://fiddle.sencha.com/?extreact#view/editor&fiddle/2n05

Fails in 6.6.0 (see console for error): https://fiddle.sencha.com/?extreact#view/editor&fiddle/2n04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get error _this.form.getValues is not a function in 6.6.0

The reason `ref={form => this.form = form}`. In **extreact-6.6.0** the form variable is not exact `formpanel`. So for this you need to access like this

```
ref={form => this.form = (this.form || form.cmp)}}
```

Another way you use [button.up('formpanel')](https://docs.sencha.com/extreact/6.6.0/modern/Ext.Button.html#method-up) to get the `formpanel` component. This button is first parameter of your [`handler`](https://docs.sencha.com/extreact/6.6.0/modern/Ext.Button.html#cfg-handler).

```
button.up('formpanel').getValues()
```

You can check here with working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2n0h).

**Code Snippet**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {launch} from '@sencha/ext-react';
import { ExtReact } from '@sencha/ext-react';
import { Container, Label, FormPanel, TextField, Button } from '@sencha/ext-modern';

class App extends Component {

    state = {
        values:JSON.stringify({
            fname: 'null',
            lname: 'null'
        })
    }

    submit = (btn) => {
        const values = btn.up('formpanel').getValues();

        console.log('Values using up selector',values);

        console.log('Values using up ref',this.form.getValues());

        this.setState({values:JSON.stringify(this.form.getValues())});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container defaults={{ margin: 10, shadow: true }}>
                <FormPanel title="Form" ref={form => this.form = (this.form || form.cmp)}>
                    <TextField name="fname" label="First Name"/>
                    <TextField name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
                    <Button handler={this.submit} text="Submit"/>
                </FormPanel>

                <Label padding={'10'} html={this.state.values} />
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

launch(<ExtReact><App /></ExtReact>);
```